# Implementar método onClickListener num fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Eu estou a desenvolver, em Android Studio, um aplicação sobre música. Nessa aplicação, eu tenho dois fragments: Home Fragment e Genres Fragment.
Dentro do Genres Fragment, eu tenho 4 ImageButton e quero adicionar-lhes um evento, ou seja, quando se clica num botão, abre outro Fragment.

Portanto, eu já tenho o código do método onClickListener dentro do ficheiro Java desse Fragment. Também tenho uma função com o operador Switch, mas não sei o que pôr dentro do case de cada botão.
Eu ando a procura de uma solução para isto há dias....já tentei com o replace() e não deu. Além disso, isto é um projeto para a escola e é um pouco urgente

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genres, container, false);

    ImageButton rapBtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.RapButton);
    ImageButton popBtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.PopButton);
    ImageButton edmBtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.EDMButton);
    ImageButton rockBtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.RockButton);
    rapBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    popBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    edmBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    rockBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.PopButton:
            // O que ponho aqui?

            break;
        case R.id.EDMButton:
            break;

        case R.id.RockButton:
            break;

        case R.id.RapButton:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ramaral eu pus uma imagem do código na pergunta

Comment: Quer abrir um Fragment em cada `case`?

Comment: @ramaral Eu quero saber o código para pôr em cada case de forma a poder abrir um fragment quando clico num botão. Eu já tentei várias hipóteses, mas sem sucesso